# How to we disable printing and copypaste for excel workbook using python win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I would like to know how do I disable printing / copypaste in excel file using python win32com.

It similar to beforeprint() and Application.cutcopypaste in VBA.

Really unable to find any answer after Google.

Thanks much.

Comment: `BeforePrint` is an event in a Workbook, but there is no event or attribute called `CutCopyPaste` in the Excel object model.  What do you mean there?

Comment: You can hook up to Excel events (like `Workbook.BeforePrint`).  Here's an example: https://support.pyxll.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360041106933-Getting-Excel-Events-in-Python

Comment: Thanks. For the cutcopy method.. I like to prevent user from 'copy and paste' the worksheet.  I still unable to hook up the BeforePrint with an Event. Will appreciate if there is a sample code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you check the link I posted?  It has example code on how to sign up for Excel events.  It's COM -- all events are the same.  And I still don't know what you mean by "cutcopy method".  There is no method or event with that name.

Comment: It is sometimes easier to prototype what you want to achieve in VBA, then replicate in win32com.